# Data validation in Excel 2010

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table with three columns of data. I am using drop down menus for the first two columns. What I would like to do is have a cell that would match the names in the two drop down menus to find the correct data in the third column. An example is: Launch Location, Takeout Location, and % on BLM are the column headings. I have drop down menus for the first two columns with 19 names in each. The third column is a % number that corresponds to name selection in the first two columns. Such as "Prospect, Big Creek, 12.17%". I would like to be able to choose two locations and have the % equal to the two selected names.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in C45 and copy down

```
=VLOOKUP($H47,$A$24:$T$42,MATCH($J47,$A$23:$T$23,0),FALSE)
```

Comment: I am trying to use drop down menus to get the % result. I have a drop down menu for Launch location F47 and Takeout Location in H47. I would like to get the percentage in J47. Would this be possible?

Comment: @David Yes then change the $A45 to $H47 and the $B45 to $F47 and place the formula in J47, sorry I had it backwards above.  Then just ensure the the search areas are correct.  You can extrapolate those from the picture you provided to match yours.  i will edit mine.

Comment: Worked Great!! Thank you for your help.